# Unable to get any rows back from V$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS in 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, rman

I have got a user `MONITOR` thru which i am running a SQL script

```
select SESSION_KEY, INPUT_TYPE, STATUS, to_char(START_TIME,'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as RMAN_BKUP_START_TIME, 
    to_char(END_TIME,'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as RMAN_BKUP_END_TIME,
    elapsed_seconds/3600 Hours 
from V$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS
where START_TIME > sysdate-7
order by END_TIME;
```

However, I am unable to get any rows back (says `now rows selected`) from user MONITOR. MONITOR has got 'SELECT ANY DICTIONARY' privilege. This is how i am connecting:

```
sqlplus MONITOR/MONITOR@prod-ora-scan:1521/MYPDB
```

I am able to get rows back using SYS user though.

Comment: Is SYS looking at the data from the same PDB; or the root container, perhaps?

Comment: Hi @AlexPoole, I am not fully sure. I am using the 'sqlplus / as sysdba'.

Comment: You can do `show con_name` or `select sys_contact('userenv', 'con_name') from dual` in both sessions?

Comment: SYS is connecting to root container CDB$ROOT. MONITOR is looking at data from PDB. Since RMAN backups are taken up at root CDB level, that explains the difference in desired output. Thanks Alex!